# Error on Eclim installation

Tags: java, eclim

I would like to install eclim, but I got error. Does anyone has idea how whats wrong?

```
$ java -jar eclim_1.7.2.jar 
Buildfile: installer.xml
2011-11-03 22:04:43,635 INFO  [org.formic.Installer] Running Installer.
2011-11-03 22:04:43,750 ERROR [ANT] 
jar:file:/home/slawosz/Downloads/eclim/eclim_1.7.2.jar!/installer.xml:36: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
    at org.formic.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:232)
    at org.formic.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:81)
    at org.formic.ant.Main.main(Main.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:306)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:159)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel.<clinit>(PlasticLookAndFeel.java:135)
    at org.formic.Installer.setLookAndFeel(Installer.java:293)
    at org.formic.Installer.run(Installer.java:109)
    at org.formic.ant.InstallerTask.execute(InstallerTask.java:89)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getScreenResolution(HeadlessToolkit.java:221)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.isLowResolution(LookUtils.java:480)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.<clinit>(LookUtils.java:249)
    ... 26 more
2011-11-03 22:04:43,767 DEBUG [ANT] 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2011-11-03 22:04:43,780 WARN  [ANT]      [echo] Installation canceled.
```

Comment: The HeadlessException implies that there is no graphic environment, which I guess is a requirement for Eclipse.  In what environment are you running the above?

Comment: Have you matched the SHA1 or MD5 sum of your installation to make sure that the installation was not corrupted.  @Necreaux thanks for suggestion

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After another try it worked without any problems on my machine.

PS. I switched vim to emacs....

Answer (score 2):

You may want to start with -Djava.awt.headless=true and see if that solves the issue... I used to run into this with old JVM's if I wanted to run certain graphing packages (back in the day).

Comment: No go: `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
...`

Answer (score 0):

eclipse may have some compatibility issue with the JVM. make sure that eclipse and JVM have same bit.(32 or 64bit)

Comment: Eclipse is a Java application... AFAIK there are no 32-bit and 64-bit Java applications.

Comment: It's true that eclipse is a java app, but the UI toolkit that it uses has quite a few native libraries, so they do distribute 32 & 64 bit versions.